# Caching Chartboost interstitial at same location

Tags: ios, caching, chartboost

It appears that caching/displaying/dismissing an interstital with a particular CBLocation only works for one cycle. Trying to load another interstitial at the same location again (even after first one is dismissed) doesn't seem to work. The listener for load_success and load_fail is never called after the first cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Chartboost seems to auto-cache the next interstitial after you cache and display at a current location.

The cache listener thus appears to get called twice.

When you try caching again (after displaying at a particular location), it does nothing as it has already cached an interstitial, so don't expect your callback to get called now.